# code first .net core publish has no database tables

Tags: database, ef-code-first, azure-devops, publish

I'm pretty new to both Azure and code first.  I have an app which works locally. I published the web project using the visual studio wizard.  All worked well.
However its missing all the db tables.

I had a look at the connection string which has a "DefaultConnection".  Locally its "Server=(localdb)\...".
In azure it appears as "Data Source=tcp:Sniipedb.database.windows.net,1433"

I have a db initializer which seeds the data but it only works locally.
My AppDBContext I assume should have created the db.

The actual error on the site online is "SqlException: Invalid object name 'Users'.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, bool breakConnection, Action wrapCloseInAction)"

When I look in the DB, however, there are no tables.

I'm making a simple chores app.  Users is a DB table.

To create users I have the following:
within startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<AppDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
    services.AddTransient<ITaskRepository, TaskRepository>();
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

within the AppDBContext : DbContext

```
public DbSet<User> Users {Get; set;}
```

User is a simple class

```
public class User
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }        
    [Key]
    public string EMailAddress { get; set; }   
    public ICollection<UserTask> UserTasks { get; set; }
}
```

I have a DBInitializer which seeds new users and saves the context.

This works flawlessly on the local machine.

Comment: Did you try to solve the issue which is mentioned like invalid object name `users` ? Is `users` is a table? please share your code

Comment: Sure, no problem @Jayendran. Its a table but when I look at the db I expected 4 tables and see none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to configure my Publish.  Within the settings it has a "databases" option where the "use this connection string at runtime" was unchecked.

Also under "Entity Framework Migrations" the "Apply this migration on publish" was unchecked.

By checking those two, then saving and then publishing it worked.